# PHP Symfony twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to make a view so that I can see all orders in the database. But the thing is that there are more products in one order and I only get it to show a row for every product. Like in the picture here:

[image: View]

I have tried moving the for loop but to no success. I hope you guys can help me.

Twig form:

```
{% extends 'layout/default.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Inkoper - Lunenburg{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Bestelordernummer</th>
                        <th scope="col">Artikelnummer</th>
                        <th scope="col">Omschrijving</th>
                        <th scope="col">Aantal</th>
                        <th scope="col">Leverancier</th>
                        <th scope="col">Magazijnlocatie</th>
                        <th scope="col">Keuringseisen</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for bestelling in bestellingen %}
                        {% for bestelregel in bestelling.bestelregels %}
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{ bestelling.bestelordernummer }}</th>
                            <td>{{ bestelregel.artikel.artikelnummer }}</td>
                            <td>{{ bestelregel.artikel.omschrijving }}</td>
                            <td>{{ bestelregel.aantal }}</td>
                            <td>{{ bestelling.leverancier }}</td>
                            <td>{{ bestelregel.artikel.magazijnlocatie }}</td>
                            <td>{{ bestelling.keuringseisen }}</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{ path('bestellingwijzigen', {'bestelling':bestelling.bestelordernummer}) }}">Wijzigen</a></td>
                        <td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Entity Artikel

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Artikel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="artikel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArtikelRepository")
 */
class Artikel
{

    //Mapping naar de database

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikelnummer", type="integer", length=20, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 10,
     *      max = 10,
     *      minMessage = "Minimaal 10 karakters",
     *      maxMessage = "Maximaal 10 karakters"
     *)
     */
    private $artikelnummer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="omschrijving", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $omschrijving;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="specificaties", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $specificaties;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Magazijnlocatie", type="string", length=6)
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^20|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][0]{1}[0-9]{1}|10$/i",
         *    match=true,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR1]")
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^[2]{1}[1-9]{1}\/[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i",
         *    match=false,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR2]")
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^[3-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][0-9]{1}$/i",
         *    match=false,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR3]")
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][1]{1}[1-9]{1}$/i",
         *    match=false,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR4]")
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][2-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i",
         *    match=false,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR5]")
         * @Assert\Regex(
         *    pattern = "/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/i",
         *    match=false,
         *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR6]")
         * @Assert\Length(
         *      max = 6,
         *      maxMessage = "Mag niet meer zijn dan {{ limit }} karakters"
         * )
         */
    private $magazijnlocatie;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     *
     * assert
     * @ORM\Column@Column(type="decimal", precision= 10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $inkoopprijs;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vervangendArtikel", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */

    private $vervangendArtikel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="minimumVoorraad", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $minimumVoorraad;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="voorraadaantal", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $voorraadaantal;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bestelserie", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $bestelserie;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verkopen", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $verkopen;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gereserveerdeVoorraad", type="integer", length=10, nullable=true)
     */

    private $gereserveerdeVoorraad;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vrijeVoorraad", type="integer", length=10, nullable=true)
     */

    private $vrijeVoorraad;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="in_voorraad", type="boolean")
     */
    private $inVoorraad;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bestelregel", mappedBy="artikel")
     */
    private $bestelregels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bestelregels = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    //**************************************************Set/Get Functies hieronder!*********************************


    /**
     * @param mixed $bestelregels
     */
    public function setBestelregels($bestelregels)
    {
        $this->bestelregels = $bestelregels;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBestelregels()
    {
        return $this->bestelregels;
    }

    /**
     * Set artikelnummer
     *
     * @param string $artikelnummer
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setArtikelnummer($artikelnummer)
    {
        $this->artikelnummer = $artikelnummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get artikelnummer
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getArtikelnummer()
    {
        return $this->artikelnummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set omschrijving
     *
     * @param string $omschrijving
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setOmschrijving($omschrijving)
    {
        $this->omschrijving = $omschrijving;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get omschrijving
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOmschrijving()
    {
        return $this->omschrijving;
    }

    /**
     * Set specificaties
     *
     * @param string $specificaties
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setSpecificaties($specificaties)
    {
        $this->specificaties = $specificaties;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get specificaties
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSpecificaties()
    {
        return $this->specificaties;
    }

    /**
     * Set magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @param string $magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setMagazijnlocatie($magazijnlocatie)
    {
        $this->magazijnlocatie = $magazijnlocatie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMagazijnlocatie()
    {
        return $this->magazijnlocatie;
    }

    /**
     * Set inkoopprijs
     *
     * @param decimal $inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setInkoopprijs($inkoopprijs)
    {
        $this->inkoopprijs = $inkoopprijs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getInkoopprijs()
    {
        return $this->inkoopprijs;
    }

    /**
     * Set vervangendArtikel
     *
     * @param string $vervangendArtikel
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setVervangendartikel($vervangendeArtikel)
    {
        $this->vervangendArtikel = $vervangendArtikel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vervangendArtikel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVervangendartikel()
    {
        return $this->vervangendArtikel;
    }

     /**
     * Set minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @param integer $minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setMinimumvoorraad($minimumVoorraad)
    {
        $this->minimumVoorraad = $minimumVoorraad;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMinimumvoorraad()
    {
        return $this->minimumVoorraad;
    }

     /**
     * Set voorraadaantal
     *
     * @param integer $voorraadaantal
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setVoorraadaantal($voorraadaantal)
    {
        $this->voorraadaantal = $voorraadaantal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get voorraadaantal
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVoorraadaantal()
    {
        return $this->voorraadaantal;
    }

     /**
     * Set bestelserie
     *
     * @param integer $bestelserie
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setBestelserie($bestelserie)
    {
       $this->bestelserie = $bestelserie;
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelserie
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBestelserie()
    {
        return $this->bestelserie;
    }

     /**
     * Set verkopen
     *
     * @param integer $verkopen
     *
     * @return Verkopen
     */
    public function setVerkopen($verkopen)
    {
       $this->verkopen= $verkopen;

       return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get verkopen
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVerkopen()
    {
        return $this->verkopen;

    }

    /**
     * Set gereserveerdeVoorraad
     *
     * @param integer $gereserveerdeVoorraad
     *
     */
    public function setGereserveerdevoorraad($gereserveerdeVoorraad)
    {
       $this->gereserveerdeVoorraad= $gereserveerdeVoorraad;

       return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gereserveerdeVoorraad
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getGereserveerdevoorraad()
    {
        return $this->gereserveerdeVoorraad;
    }

    /**
     * Set vrijeVoorraad
     *
     * @param integer $vrijeVoorraad
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setVrijevoorraad($vrijeVoorraad)
    {
       $this->vrijeVoorraad= $vrijeVoorraad;

       return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vrijeVoorraad
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVrijevoorraad()
    {
        return $this->vrijeVoorraad;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getInVoorraad()
    {
        return $this->inVoorraad;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $inVoorraad
     */
    public function setInVoorraad($inVoorraad)
    {
        $this->inVoorraad = $inVoorraad;
    }

}
```

Entity Bestelling

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Bestelling
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bestelling")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BestellingRepository")
 */
class Bestelling
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bestelordernummer", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $bestelordernummer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="leverancier", type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 6,
     *      minMessage = "Minimaal 1 karakters",
     *      maxMessage = "Maximaal 6 karakters"
     *)
     */
    private $leverancier;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="keuringseisen", type="integer", length=4, nullable=true)
     */
    private $keuringseisen;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bestelregel", mappedBy="bestelling", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $bestelregels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bestelregels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bestelregels
     */
    public function setBestelregels($bestelregels)
    {
        $this->bestelregels = $bestelregels;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBestelregels()
    {
        return $this->bestelregels;
    }

    /**
     * Set bestelordernummer
     *
     * @param integer $bestelordernummer
     *
     * @return Bestelling
     */
    public function setBestelordernummer($bestelordernummer)
    {
        $this->bestelordernummer = $bestelordernummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelordernummer
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBestelordernummer()
    {
        return $this->bestelordernummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set leverancier
     *
     * @param string $leverancier
     *
     * @return Bestelling
     */
    public function setLeverancier($leverancier)
    {
        $this->leverancier = $leverancier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get leverancier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLeverancier()
    {
        return $this->leverancier;
    }


    /**
     * Set keuringseisen
     *
     * @param integer $keuringseisen
     *
     * @return Bestelling
     */
    public function setKeuringseisen($keuringseisen)
    {
        $this->keuringseisen = $keuringseisen;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get keuringseisen
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getKeuringseisen()
    {
        return $this->keuringseisen;
    }
}
```

Entity Bestelregel (join table)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Bestelregel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bestelregel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BestelregelRepository")
 */
class Bestelregel
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artikel", inversedBy="bestelregels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artikelnummer", referencedColumnName="artikelnummer")
     */
    private $artikel;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bestelling", inversedBy="bestelregels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bestelordernummer", referencedColumnName="bestelordernummer")
     */
    private $bestelling;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="aantal", type="integer")
     */
    private $aantal;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getArtikel()
    {
        return $this->artikel;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $artikel
     */
    public function setArtikel($artikel)
    {
        $this->artikel = $artikel;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBestelling()
    {
        return $this->bestelling;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bestelling
     */
    public function setBestelling($bestelling)
    {
        $this->bestelling = $bestelling;
    }

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return Bestelregel
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAantal()
    {
        return $this->aantal;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $aantal
     */
    public function setAantal($aantal)
    {
        $this->aantal = $aantal;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
<?php
//Namespace en uses, mag je vergeten. Moet er wel in staan!
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Bestelregel;
use AppBundle\Entity\Bestelling;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\BestellingType;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\BestelregelType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Artikel;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\ArtikelType;

class BestellingController extends Controller
{

    //Functie om als inkoper alle bestelopdrachten te kunnen zien

    /**
     * @Route ("/inkoper/bestelopdrachten/", name="allebestelopdrachten")
     */
    public function alleBestelopdrachten(Request $request){

        $bestellingen = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Bestelling")->findAll();

        //Verwijzing naar formulier
        return $this->render('inkoper/bestelregel.html.twig', [
            'bestellingen' => $bestellingen
        ]);

    }

    //Functie om als inkoper een nieuwe bestelling te kunnen maken

    /**
    * @Route("/inkoper/bestelling/nieuw", name="bestellingnieuw")
    */
    public function nieuweBestelling (Request $request) {
        $nieuweBestelling = new Bestelling();
        $form = $this->createForm(BestellingType::class, $nieuweBestelling);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            foreach ($nieuweBestelling->getBestelregels() as $bestelregel) {
                $bestelregel->setBestelling($nieuweBestelling);
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($nieuweBestelling);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("allebestelopdrachten"));
        }

        //Verwijzing naar formulier
        return $this->render('inkoper/form.bestelling.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Bestelling toevoegen',
        ]);
    }

    //Als inkoper een bestelling kunnen wijzigen.

    /**
     * @Route("/inkoper/bestelling/wijzigen/{bestelling}", name="bestellingwijzigen")
     */
    public function editBestelling (Request $request, $bestelling) {
        $bestaandeBestelling = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Bestelling")->find($bestelling);
        $form = $this->createForm(BestellingType::class, $bestaandeBestelling);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            foreach ($bestaandeBestelling->getBestelregels() as $bestelregel) {
                $bestelregel->setBestelling($bestaandeBestelling);
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($bestaandeBestelling);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("allebestelopdrachten"));
        }

        //Verwijzing naar formulier
        return $this->render('inkoper/form.bestelling.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Bestelling wijzigen',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose you need to rewrite your query which gets products.

Comment: doctrine entities set an attribute called "id", that is the identifier of the entity (rows of the table db), update your question show us your entity, expecifically

Comment: @jjoselon I've edited the post.

Comment: And how does your controller look like ? The view is only meant to render the data. Not for sorting or anything.

Comment: @FrankB Added it aswell.

Comment: So what do you want to see on the screen in the table? Only the orders? In that case you dont need two for loops but only one that irritates the orders. You could give each order a link that directs the user to the order details where you could show all order rows (bestelregels)